# How to force visual studio project installer to complete setup?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am creating an update for a C# .net program that already used visual studio installer project as setup-project. The new setup works fine if no previous version of the program is installed, however, when a previous version is already installed, it doesn't seem to fully complete in one go. For example the main .exe file isn't installed in the program folder yet. Then if I click on the installed shortcut in the start menu or desktop, the windows installer is activated again and the installer does complete the installation and everything works. However, I really would like it to complete the installation immediately when the setup is run, I don't like this 'postponed' installation thing.

Any idea what causes this or how I can fix it?

thanks!

Comment: [Have you set up a proper upgrade](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/)? (aging article, but should be ok).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Eventually I was able to fix this issue by editing the msi file with Orca. I moved the 'remove previous products' action to BEFORE the install new products actions. The problem was something like it first detected a lot of files that did not have newer version numbers (no idea how to set individual files version numbers), and those were not overwritten. Then at the end a -remove previous product' action would remove all these 'not upgrade' files and many files were then missing. This seems to be some kind of bug or design problem and I couldn't find a 'proper fix'...